# Clear select2 multiple when specified value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I try to implement following scenario in select2 multiple select.

1. User chooses some options
2. User chooses 'No Required Programs' in select
3. Select cleans up all the selected values
4. Select has a placeholder with the following text: 'No Required Features'

Here is my html:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="transfer_posting[pap_facility_feature_ids][]" id="transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids"><option value="No Required Features">No Required Features</option>
  <option value="13">Pool</option>
  <option value="15">Sauna</option>
  <option value="16">Salon</option>
  <option value="17">Massage</option>
</select>
```

and javascript:

```
$('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select Feature(s)',
  allowClear: true
});

$('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
  var selectedFeature = e.params.args.data.text
    console.log(selectedFeature);
  if (selectedFeature === 'No Required Features') {
    $('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').val(null).trigger("change");

    $('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').select2({
      placeholder: 'No Required Features'
    });

  }
});
```

Here is the link to js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxqc76e8/3/

How should I update my code to make this scenario works?

Comment: Sorry but not able to understand what you actually want. can you please be more descriptive

Comment: @ankitverma: When User select 'No Required Features' in select in my jsfiddle I want to cleanup select so it will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the updated fiddle code. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akit/mxqc76e8/4/) 

Added some condition with code changes a bit 
Hope it will help you

```
$('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select Feature(s)',
  allowClear: true
});

$('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
    if ($("#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids option[value='No Required Features']:selected").length > 0){
    alert('No Required Feture is selected');
    exit;
    }
  var selectedFeature = e.params.args.data.text
 if (selectedFeature =='No Required Features') {    
    $('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').select2({
      placeholder: 'No Required Features'
    });
    $('li.select2-selection__choice').remove();
  $('#transfer_posting_pap_facility_feature_ids').val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm choosing 'Pool', then I choosing 'No Required Features' and select still contains values. It should be empty after selecting 'No Required Features'

Comment: When I use 'No Required Features' it throws errors in browser console: 
ReferenceError: exit is not defined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akit/mxqc76e8/6/ check this fiddle , i have replaced exit with return statement